# Could not complete the operation due to error c00ce514

Tags: asp.net

I'm having a problem with downloading  excel file created by server side.  I keep getting the following error:

Could not complete the operation due to error c00ce514.

Comment: Have you tried googling for "c00ce514" ? First hit seems useful...

Answer (score 1):

The problem could maybe have something to do with your character set, but not sure

Answer (score 0):

It could be taking too long and causing a session timeout.